# MS Access and SOAP, XMLRPC etc

Tags: web-services, ms-access, soap, xml-rpc

I have been searching high and low on Google and finding very little information on using Web services with MS Access 2007. I'm sure this is possible somehow but I can't find any relevant information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look a Danny Delasandrini's article on [consuming web services from Access](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3567511/Consume-Web-Service-from-Access.htm). That should get you started, at least, (though it predates A2007 and A2010).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, what has worked for me in the past is to build a com-callable .NET component, install it on the user's machine, and reference the COM-interface from the access database using VBA.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work! I'm not real familiar with .net, how much work would be involved in making some sort of "adapter" from my wsdl to a COM interface that I could use in Access? Is that a loaded question or what?!

Comment: It's really not that much work, but if you're not familiar with .NET, a dll created with VB6 would work as well. Here's a decent article on calling a SOAP service from VB6: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/VB.NET/Calling-a-Web-Service-using-VB6-with-SOAP-30/ you might even consider adapting the VB6 article to VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I was developing and integration between MS Access 2010 and WordPress 4.0 using XMLRPC. I documented the process and some code in 8 articles:

[1) Post publish](http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com.ar/2014/09/publicar-en-wordpress-desde-microsoft.html)

[2) File upload](http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com.ar/2014/09/publicar-en-wordpress-desde-microsoft_12.html)

[3) Featured image](http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com.ar/2014/09/publicar-en-wordpress-desde-microsoft_21.html)

[4) Custom Type](http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com.ar/2014/09/publicar-en-wordpress-desde-microsoft_48.html)

[5) Custom Fields](http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com.ar/2014/09/publicar-en-wordpress-desde-microsoft_35.html)

[6) The complete proccess](http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com.ar/2014/09/publicar-en-wordpress-desde-microsoft_15.html)

[7) Security](http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com.ar/2014/09/publicar-en-wordpress-desde-microsoft_23.html)

[8) Post delete](http://viviendoenlaeradelaweb20.blogspot.com.ar/2014/09/publicar-en-wordpress-desde-microsoft_25.html)

I hope it will be helpful for somebody. It was very difficult to me to find documentation.

But it works like a charm!